# best way to integrate wordpress forms with mailchimp

Tags: wordpress

How to integrate word press with mailchimp? is this possible to integrate with mailchimp?

Comment: yes this is possible and various plugins are available on Wordpress plugin repository for it => https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=mailchimp

Answer (score 0):

you can use MailChimp for WordPress plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" answer to this question really depends on what you mean by "integrate" but it is relatively easy to add sign-up methods for your MailChimp lists to your site using the mentioned [MailChimp for WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/).

The plugin gives you the option to create sign-up forms for your MailChimp lists and allows adding simple sign-up checkboxes to, say, your comment form etc.

There are various add-ons for the plugin available which let you do pop-ups, top bars and other marketing gimmicks.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to create more than one opt-in form for your site, have a look at:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yikes-inc-easy-mailchimp-extender/

All you need to do to link up your site with your MailChimp account is provide your API key, which can be retrieved in the account settings of your MailChimp account.

Once connected, you'll have access to your MailChimp account lists, account/profile details, full access to your subscribers and their associated details and more.

A "form builder" is included in the plugin, allowing you to completely build up and customize your forms so it fits in well with your site. There is also a Google reCAPTCHA module included, to help prevent from spammers.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).